# Rewrite Regex to support both scenarios

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to get all values with `secure` prefix:

```
"secure[^:]+:\s*"[^"]+"
```

It works fine for the following string:

```
Parameters: {"client_id":"6dd930eb-e4dc-48d9-a18b-ace0c7406dc8","secure_client_secret":"fedfc0a7-af1e-413c-ab51-1955113b2123"}
```

but it does not work for the following string:

```
"Parameters: {\"client_id\":\"6dd930eb-e4dc-48d9-a18b-ace0c7406dc8\",\"secure_client_secret\":\"fedfc0a7-af1e-413c-ab51-1955113b2123\"}"
```

How can I update this to work for both scenarios?
Here is link to rubular: https://rubular.com/r/ZA0ioy8mHXOghq

Comment: Just add [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) backslash [like this](https://rubular.com/r/qesMRNDgM9xGHX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a capture use and back-reference to match `"` and `\"` wrapped values:

```
(\\"|")secure[^:]+:\s*\1.*?\1
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://rubular.com/r/2jE6fhHxn0qm2X)

However do note that if your platform/tool allows it then use a proper JSON parser to parse a JSON string like this.